# Apache server status codes

Tags: apache

Is there a way, on apache server, to make a specified page, to send code 404 in browser?

I work on an application, where if you tap a url that is not recognised, the application sends code 302, and makes a redirect instead of a page `error.html` who send code 200 which is normal because is a page who exist.

I need to modify the code for page `error.html` in 404 from `httpd.conf`.

Can you help me please?

I've tried with ErrorDocument 404 /error, but the application does not send 404, it sends 302. I need to rewrite this 302 in 404.

Answer (score 1):

create an error page 404.html on the httpd DocumentRoot.
Add `ErrorDocument 404 /404.html` in httpd.conf.
Restart Apache and access a page that does not exist.